# Unable to instantiate componentinfo with SlidingMenu Library and SlidingFragmentActivity

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am developing an appliation in Android with the SlidingMenu library. I've imported the project to eclipse and I've linked the library with my project PaperTask. The MainActivity extend from SlidingFragmentActivity that extend from FragmentActivity. I've added the class to the Android Manifest but when I launch the app, the debugger show this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.paper.papertask/com.paper.papertask.activities.MainPaperActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.paper.papertask.activities.MainPaperActivity" 
on path: /data/app/com.paper.papertask-2.apk
```

The android manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.paper.papertask"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.paper.papertask.activities.MainPaperActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

The routes of my class are the correct, but for some reason this not found the class. 
[image: Image of the archive of my project]

Can some one know why this doesn't find the class?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same error. The problem is in extending the FragmentActivity. Still searching for a solution.

Comment: Now I am using the google navigation drawer because I could not fix the extend to FragmentActivity. The navigation drawer need the new android support library but it work great.